# Volleyball match broadcasting software

Tags: streaming, sport

I play a lot of volleyball and beach volleyball, and I'd like a system to record and broadcast my games. My specific vision is something like this:

- You can create a new match using your phone, and add the team info and whatever other metadata you want
- After the match is created, you can get two RMTP links for an A-cam (stationary shot) and a B-cam (POV shot)
- You can connect to those RMTP links and start streaming to them via camera like an iPhone or GoPro
- After you create the match and connect the cameras, you can start the broadcast, which will start by just showing the B-cam
- When the scoreboard changes, the stream switches from the B-cam a replay from the A-cam
- When a new rally starts, the stream switches back to the B-cam
- The scoreboard and team info should be visible at all times during the stream
- Match replays should be persisted to a database
- Via an Apple Watch or similar wearable device, you can update the scoreboard, and record when a new rally has started

Is there any software out there that could help me achieve something like this?

Comment: I think you have your sights set a bit high, tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) + extensions/external software (including your own for e.g. Apple Watch integration or persisiting replays which definitely don't exist, unless as different unrelated software) + proper config + a person controlling the stream. Way too specific to achieve this easily.